# BackgroundWorker C#, Read from txt files - Write to a csv

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

The following code actually does what i want it to do however I'm trying to make it optimal and as im still learning about the BackgroundWorker etc I thought you could give me a few tips. The trouble is I can run the program but because it's quite a long operation (1000's+ lines per text file), it doeant update the progressbar or labels very well only until the program completes. there are 2 progreesbars, one for the number of text files processed and the other for the number of lines read of the text file in the process.

```
namespace myParser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    string filePath;
    string[] files;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pbFilesProcessed.Visible = false;
        pbLinesProcessed.Visible = false;
        btnParse.Visible = false;
        lbProcessedFiles.Visible = false;
        lbProcessedLines.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //counts the number of files in the folder
            files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

            filePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();

            char[] delimiterChars = { '\\' };
            string[] filePathParts = filePath.Split(delimiterChars);

            string folder = filePathParts[4];

            tbFolderName.Text = folder;

            btnParse.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnParse.Visible = false;

        lbProcessedFiles.Visible = true;
        pbFilesProcessed.Visible = true;
        lbProcessedLines.Visible = true;
        pbLinesProcessed.Visible = true;
        lbProcessedLines.Text = "Lines: 0 / 0";

        int fileCount = 1;

        foreach (var csvFile in Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
        {
            pbFilesProcessed.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length.ToString());

            string fileName = "Waveforms.csv";

            int lineCount = 0;

            string lines;

            string newLines;              

            string csvFullFilePath = csvFile.ToString();
            string[] filePathSplit = csvFullFilePath.Split('\\');
            string pointName = filePathSplit[4].ToString();

            string[] pathDirectionSplit = filePathSplit[5].ToString().Split('_');
            string[] swingDirectionSplit = pathDirectionSplit[3].Split('.');
            string swingDirection = swingDirectionSplit[0];


            var numberOfLines = File.ReadLines(csvFile).Count();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(csvFile))
            {
                while ((lines = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    pbLinesProcessed.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfLines.ToString());

                    if (lineCount == 0)
                    {
                        lines.Remove(0);
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newLines = Regex.Replace(lines, ",{2,}", ",").ToString();
                        File.AppendAllText(@"Simulator\\" + fileName, pointName + "," + swingDirection + "," + newLines + System.Environment.NewLine);

                        pbLinesProcessed.PerformStep();
                        lbProcessedLines.Text = "Lines: " + lineCount + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(numberOfLines.ToString()); 

                        lineCount++;                                  
                    }
                }
                r.Close();
            }
            pbFilesProcessed.PerformStep();
            lbProcessedFiles.Text = "Files: " + fileCount.ToString() + "/" + files.Length.ToString();
            fileCount++;
        }
        btnParse.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a reference to BackgroundWorker here...

Comment: @medinoc - Yes, ive spent the last two hours trying to incorporate it, resulting in the mayhem on the operation of the program. I shall however attempt it again and include in the above question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ Tom W - I intended to incorporate the BackgroundWorker into the code after i had failed miserably, this was down to my own laziness. The post below (marked as the Answer), i read and implemented. now i have a working solution albeit not as perfect, which im sure someone will point out. Ill attempt to answer my own question and post the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, after an hour or so, this is what i have done. not the most elegant as im still a novice Thanks to nim (MSDN Link). However i am having trouble getting the correct amount of progress shown on the progressbar.....

```
namespace myParser
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string filePath;
    string[] files;
    int fileCount = 0;
    int numberOfFiles;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int numberOfLines;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pbFilesProcessed.Visible = false;
        pbLinesProcessed.Visible = false;
        btnParse.Visible = false;
        lbProcessedFiles.Visible = false;
        lbProcessedLines.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //counts the number of files in the folder
            files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

            filePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();

            char[] delimiterChars = { '\\' };
            string[] filePathParts = filePath.Split(delimiterChars);

            string folder = filePathParts[4];

            tbFolderName.Text = folder;

            btnParse.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnParse.Visible = false;
        btnOpen.Visible = false;

        lbProcessedFiles.Visible = true;
        pbFilesProcessed.Visible = true;
        lbProcessedLines.Visible = true;
        pbLinesProcessed.Visible = true;
        lbProcessedLines.Text = "Lines: 0 / 0";

        pbFilesProcessed.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length.ToString());

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var csvFile in Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
        {
            numberOfFiles = Convert.ToInt32(files.Length.ToString());

            string fileName = "Waveforms.csv";
            lineCount = 0;
            string lines;
            string newLines;
            string csvFullFilePath = csvFile.ToString();
            string[] filePathSplit = csvFullFilePath.Split('\\');
            string pointName = filePathSplit[4].ToString();
            string[] pathDirectionSplit = filePathSplit[5].ToString().Split('_');
            string[] swingDirectionSplit = pathDirectionSplit[3].Split('.');
            string swingDirection = swingDirectionSplit[0];

            numberOfLines = File.ReadLines(csvFile).Count();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(csvFile))
            {
                while ((lines = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (lineCount == 0)
                    {
                        lines.Remove(0);
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newLines = Regex.Replace(lines, ",{2,}", ",").ToString();
                        File.AppendAllText(@"Simulator\\" + fileName, pointName + "," + swingDirection + "," + newLines + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(lineCount);
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                }
                r.Close();
            }
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(fileCount);
            fileCount++;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbFilesProcessed.PerformStep();
        lbProcessedFiles.Text = "Files: " + fileCount.ToString() + "/" + files.Length.ToString();
        pbLinesProcessed.PerformStep();
        lbProcessedLines.Text = "Lines: " + lineCount + "/" + Convert.ToInt32(numberOfLines.ToString());
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnParse.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
        btnOpen.Visible = true;
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [MSDN documentation on BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

There is a very short but good sample code near bottom of the page.